# Drupal 7 Views - Add a wrapper around rows for unformatted list from admin panel

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a views which rendered html like this

```
<div class="content">
<div class="row-1">Some Text here</div>
<div class="row-2">Some Text here</div>
<div class="row-3">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to wrap the rows using a wrapper div like so.

```
<div class="content">
<div class="wrapper-1">
<div class="row-1">Some Text here</div>
<div class="row-2">Some Text here</div>
<div class="row-3">Some Text here</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the style output template of the views/display. You will find it in "Theming information". To get it from your views/display do:

> Advanced > Theme: information

The first template is "views-view-unformatted.tpl.php" but you can use any in the list.

The original code is:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Add your wrapper around the foreach and you are done.

Comment: I want to add a wrapper div from admin panel.

Comment: Administration panel ... Do you mean the view/display configuration page? You don't want to use code?

Comment: Yes, from views configuration page. I don't want to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way to do this, but you can try the following for Drupal 7::

```
function MODULENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {

    if ($vars['view']->name == 'VIEWNAME') {
        $vars['rows'] = "<div class='wrapper-class'>" . $vars['rows'] . "</div>";
    }

}
```

This will wrap contents just below the `view-content` class.